# Eigen3: extract a submatrix with a non constant number of columns

Tags: c++, eigen3, submatrix

I wrote the following function in C++, using Eigen3:

```
MatrixXf transformPoints(MatrixXf X, MatrixXf P)
{
    // create a new matrix to host points
    MatrixXf tempMatrix = MatrixXf::Zero(4, P.cols());

    // extract rotational and traslational parts from X
    MatrixXf rotmat = tempMatrix.block<2,2>(0,0);
    Vector2f traMat = tempMatrix.block<2,1>(0,2);

    // separate points from normals
    // int cols_of_P = P.cols();
    MatrixXf points = tempMatrix.block<2,P.cols()>(0,0);
    MatrixXf normals = tempMatrix.block<2,P.cols()>(2,0);
}
```

In my idea, on last two rows, I should be able to extract a submatrix from p, whose number of column is not known a priori, but it depends on P's size.
I get the following error:

```
home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/thesis_pack/src/least_squares_utilities.h: In function ‘Eigen::MatrixXf least_squares::transformPoints(Eigen::MatrixXf, Eigen::MatrixXf)’:
/home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/thesis_pack/src/least_squares_utilities.h:18:47: error: ‘P’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
/home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/thesis_pack/src/least_squares_utilities.h:18:49: error: ‘.’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
/home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/thesis_pack/src/least_squares_utilities.h:18:54: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
/home/ubisum/fuerte_workspace/thesis_pack/src/least_squares_utilities.h:18:60: error: no matching function for call to ‘Eigen::Matrix<float, -0x00000000000000001, -0x00000000000000001>::block(int, int)’
```

I even tried the following modification:

```
int cols_of_P = P.cols();
MatrixXf points = tempMatrix.block<2,cols_of_P>(0,0);
MatrixXf normals = tempMatrix.block<2,cols_of_P>(2,0);
```

but nothing changed.
Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Template arguments are required to be compile time constant - invariably. Neither `P` nor `cols_of_P` is a compile time coinstant expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the documentation for Using Block Operations.

There are two versions, whose syntax is as follows:

**Block operation** with
block of size `(p,q)`, starting at `(i,j)`

Version constructing a dynamic-size block expression

```
matrix.block(i,j,p,q);
```

Version constructing a 
 fixed-size block expression

```
matrix.block<p,q>(i,j);
```

For your case use:

```
tempMatrix.block(0, 0, 2, 2)
```